# How do you add an array element(int) and an integer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

I am trying to add an integer and an array element(also integer) but I seem to be concatenating them instead. How would I add the two together?

```
i = 0;
var1 = 0;
var2 = prompt("please enter 5 integers separated by commas");
   //1,2,3,4,5  
var2.split(',');
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
    var1 += var2[i];
}
```

EDIT: Apologies I forgot something that's probably very important. I'll add that now. added the prompt and the split.

Comment: Make `var2 = [1,2,3,4,5]` and you're good

Comment: You have edited the question with the correct answer.. Please re run & check.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the integer to every element of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var2.split(',')` does not update `var2`. You would have to do `var2 = var2.split(',')`. You can also use `.reduce` to sum the array instead of iterating over it with a `for` loop:

```
var1 += var2.split(',').map(Number).reduce((prev, next) => prev + next);
```

Answer (score 0):

var2 was not an an array, which you have edited. Also instead of 5 put `var2.length` and declare a variable with `var` keyword

```
var i = 0;
var var1 = 0;
var var2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];  

for (i=0;i<var2.length;i++){
    var1 += var2[i];
}
```

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8eLfo8kb/2/)

**NOTE**  Original question got edited after this post

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in the script

```js
i = 0;
var1 = 0;
var2 = prompt("please enter 5 integers separated by commas");
//1,2,3,4,5  
var array = var2.split(','); //need to iterate over the array
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { //instead of hardcoded length go by the array length
  console.log(array[i])
  var1 += +array[i]; //or parseInt(var2[i])
}
alert(var1)
```